# Dialogflow: Set multiple contexts using fulfillment library (node.js) in Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm trying to set/change multiple contexts based on user's response. For this, I am trying to set output context by **agent.setContext()** using fulfillment library through inline editor (node.js). I want to delete contexts set by intent in dialogflow and add new context in Dialogflow's output contexts.

**It works fine when setting one output context by calling with agent.setContext() in node.js but it throws error when I pass a list of multiple contexts in agent.setContext() as shown below:**

Note: I have given 3 output contexts (context_name_1, context_name_2, context_name_3) in the Dialogflow Intent's Output Context

Code Snippet:

```
function intent_name(agent) {
    ... // defined text response for user
    ...
    agent.setContext([{
            'name':'context_name_1',
            'lifespan': 10
            }, 
          {
            'name':'context_name_2',
            'lifespan': 0
            }, 
          {
            'name':'context_name_3',
            'lifespan': 0
            },
          {
            'name':'context_name_4',
            'lifespan': 3
            }]);
    ....
    }
```

I get error as:

```
Error: context must be provided and must have a name
    at WebhookClient.setContext (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:343:13)
    at prepaidRecharge (/srv/index.js:45:15)
    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:303:44)
    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:92:9)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Set them individually...

```
agent.setContext({ name: 'context_name_1', lifespan: 10, parameters: { city: 'Rome' }});
agent.setContext({ name: 'context_name_2', lifespan: 11, parameters: { continent: 'eu' }});
```

Or using the new way:

```
agent.context.set('context_name_1', 10, {'param1' : 'abc'});
agent.context.set('context_name_2', 11, {'param2' : 2});
```